# Remote monitor PM2 using command prompt?

Tags: pm2

I have 20+ servers that I just started using PM2 with.  It's working great but I would like a way to check in on them even if it's just real-time.  I checked out pm2.io by keymetrics but it's prohibitively expensive for my project.  Is there was a way to monitor remote servers from my local computer using `pm2 monit` or something similar?